# How to see posts in taxonomy endpoint

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, rest-api, wp-api

I am looking at a custom taxonomy endpoint and there are custom post types for this taxonomy but they don't show in the endpoint. Is there something I need to add to this endpoint or something to the registering of the custom post type/taxonomy?

http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/experiences/7

This just gives me fields `id, count, description, link, name, slug, taxonomy, parent, meta, links`. But no actual custom post type data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments:

> I just wanted to find out if there was a core endpoint for listing
> custom taxonomies with associated post type records.

And as I said in my original answer: (slightly modified, though)

> The endpoint in question is a taxonomy *term* endpoint which returns
> the data (e.g. description, name and slug) for a specific term, but
> the response does *not* include posts in that term because posts have
> their own endpoints (e.g. `/wp/v2/your_post_type?experiences=7` to get
> posts of the `your_post_type` type in the custom `experiences`
> taxonomy for term with the ID 7), but only if the post type is
> [enabled in the REST
> API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-rest-api-support-for-custom-content-types/)

So no, there is no core endpoint that works out-of-the-box like regular term archive pages like one at `example.com/category/uncategorized`, `example.com/?cat=1` or `example.com/experiences/foo-bar` (where `experiences` is a custom taxonomy slug), which by default displays posts from *all or any **post types*** associated with the *taxonomy* of the requested *term*.

> I was hoping I could get this from one endpoint

> Perhaps a custom end point would be better in this case

Yes, that's an easy way as opposed to making multiple API requests for the different post types associated with your taxonomy, and it also saves you from possibly having to do complex JS coding for dealing with paging.

But actually, you could just make use of the [Search endpoint (`/wp/v2/search`)](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/search-results/#list-search-results) along with the [`rest_post_search_query` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_post_search_query/) to modify the search query args which will be passed to `WP_Query`.

So that means, just like you can control the main WordPress query via the `pre_get_posts` hook, you can also control the Search endpoint query via the above filter.

So you can add taxonomy queries, meta queries, [etc](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/parse_query/#parameters).

And here's an example that you can try, where you would make a request to `/wp/v2/search?type=post&<taxonomy slug>=<term ID or slug>`, e.g. `/wp/v2/search?type=post&experiences=7` or `/wp/v2/search?type=post&experiences=term-slug`.

**Notes:**

- The `type=post` above must always be that and it's not a post type! Instead, it means you're searching for posts.
- In the response, the actual post type (slug) is in the property named `subtype`.

```php
add_filter( 'rest_post_search_query', 'my_rest_post_search_query', 10, 2 );
function my_rest_post_search_query( $query_args, $request ) {
    $tax_query  = array();
    $post_types = array();

    $tax_objects = get_taxonomies( array(
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
    ), 'objects' );

    foreach ( $tax_objects as $taxonomy => $tax_object ) {
        if ( ! empty( $request[ $taxonomy ] ) ) {
            $tax_query[] = array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'terms'    => $request[ $taxonomy ],
                'field'    => is_numeric( $request[ $taxonomy ] ) ? 'term_id' : 'slug',
            );

            $post_types = array_merge( $post_types, (array) $tax_object->object_type );
        }
    }

    if ( ! empty( $tax_query ) ) {
        $query_args['tax_query'] = $tax_query;
        $query_args['post_type'] = $post_types;
    }

    return $query_args;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer Sally. Will read through it in more detail shortly but going back to your first line. What I essentially would like to do is going to a custom taxonomy endpoint and see all the custom post type entries for that taxonomy there. So, if the custom taxonomy was CARS, when I hit that endpoint I would like to see the custom post type entries I created there eg: AUDI, BMW, CHEV, TOYOTA, HYUNDAI and so on. PS. I do have the `show_in_rest` set to true already.

Comment: That isn't implemented in core, but as an alternative, you could use the `/wp/v2/taxonomies/experiences` endpoint to get the post types in the taxonomy, and then use the `/wp/v2/types` endpoint to get the post type data?

Comment: Sorry, to further elaborate I basically want to use javascript to get data from the api and render it on the page. If I have 2 tabs (category names) I want to list the post type records in each tab. I was hoping I could get this from one endpoint so I could basically loop through the categories and it's associated posts. In each iteration I would display the category tab and list the post type data. Perhaps a custom end point would be better in this case? I just wanted to find out if there was a core endpoint for listing custom taxonomies with associated post type records.

Comment: "Perhaps a custom end point would be better in this case?" - yes, maybe. But on what page does your JS calls the REST API? A custom plugin options page? Using jQuery?

Comment: No, not jQuery. Using a frontend framework to get data from the WordPress API.

Comment: I think there's one or two options that might work for you, but I'm not currently able to revise my answer at this hour.

Comment: All good, thanks Sally. Whenever you get a chance is perfect.

Comment: I've just revised my answer. I hope that one answered the question.. :)

Comment: Hi there, apologies for the delayed response. Thanks so much, that works really well! :)